# Packaging supporting R code in a python module?

Tags: python, r, packaging

I am trying to package some of my Python code that calls R code using [rpy2](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2.html). That R code currently sits in a separate file which I `source` from the Python script. For example, if the python script is `myscript.py`, then the R code is stored in `myscript_support.R`, and I have something like the following in `myscript.py`:

```
from rpy2.robjects import *

# Load the R code
r.source(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "myscript_support.R"))

# Call the R function
r[["myscript_R_function"]]()
```

I now want to package this Python script using setuptools, and I have a few questions:

1. How should I package the R support code, and once I have done so, how do I find the path to the R file so I can source it?
2. The R code depends on several *R* packages. How can I ensure that these are installed? Should I just raise an informative error if these R packages cannot be loaded?

Answer (score 5):

This question might be dated, but I ran into the same issue today and wanted to provide more detail for the question 1 solution suggested by @ivan_pozdeev and a new solution for question 2.

1) Edit your setup.py file to:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    ...
    # If any package contains *.r files, include them:
    package_data={'': ['*.r', '*.R']},
    include_package_data=True)
    )
```

2) Conda is quickly becoming a good option for dealing with package dependencies across both python and R. You can create an environment (http://conda.pydata.org/docs/using/envs), download all the r and python packages that you might need, and then generate an environment.yml file so that anyone can replicate your environment. Check out this blog for more info: https://www.continuum.io/content/conda-data-science

Answer (score 3):

Well, imagine yourself as the setuptools packager and think of what you would expect the programmer to do.

- Setuptools knows nothing about R, its files' structure or that your code uses them somehow.
- Your R interpreter knows nothing about importing files from Python .egg's

For the first problem, you have two choices:

1. Tell setuptools to just include some additional files without bothering what they are
2. Teach setuptools about R, how to determine what R files your program uses and how to track and include their dependencies

The first option is implementable by passing `include_package_data = True` to `setup()` and providing masks of files to include in `package_data` ([setuptools docs, "Including Data Files" section](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/setuptools#including-data-files)). Paths relative to packages' directories can be used. The files will be accessible at run time at the same relative paths through the "Resource Management API" (["Accessing Data Files at Runtime" section](http://svn.python.org/projects/sandbox/trunk/setuptools/setuptools.txt)).

The second option would require you to add your code to setuptools before invoking `setup()`. For example, you may [add a file finder](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/setuptools#adding-support-for-other-revision-control-systems) to add relevant .R files to the results of `find_packages()`. Or just generate the list of files for the previous paragraph by arbitrary means.

For the second problem, the easiest way is to force setuptools to install the package as a directory rather than an .egg by specifying [`zip_safe = False`](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/setuptools#setting-the-zip-safe-flag).
You might use `eager_resources` option instead that extracts a group of resources on demand (["Automatic Resource Extraction" section](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/setuptools#automatic-resource-extraction)).

As for installing third-party R packages, an automatable technique is described at [R Installation and Administration - Installing packages](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-admin.html#Installing-packages)

Answer (score 0):

> How should I package the R support
>   code, and once I have done so, how do
>   I find the path to the R file so I can
>   source it?

For the source files to be installed, you need to specify them in some way in `package_data`. You can find their path in the exact same way as you do now.

> The R code depends on several R
>   packages. How can I ensure that these
>   are installed? Should I just raise an
>   informative error if these R packages
>   cannot be loaded?

Either make `setup.py` check if they exist (kind of "configtools approach") or just raise some kind of exception once you cannot load them. Or maybe do both of them, and then if for some reason the files you depend on disappear, at least you will know it.

Comment: My current solution for finding the R support code assumes that the python script and the R script reside in the same directory. I can use `mymodule.__file__` instead of `__file__` to make the path relative to the module, and not the wrapper script that setuptools will install in `$PATH`, but how do I figure out where setuptools is putting the module file and tell setuptools to install the R script in the same directory? Also, will any of thie work if the whole package is put inside an egg file?

Comment: Put the R files somewhere inside the module, and specify them in `package_data`. Like this, setuptools should install them at the exact same place (relative to the module).

Comment: As for the egg file, see http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/PkgResources#basic-resource-access