# Including data files with setuptools

Tags: python, setuptools

I'm making a `Python` package using `setuptools`, and I want to include fairly extensive example data files. Note that I need users to be able to access the data files *directly* -- they are not just required for my script.

So, I can run `python setup.py install` without a problem, but 'my_data_files' don't actually appear to be installed anywhere.  My understanding from the documentation [here](http://python-packaging-user-guide.readthedocs.org/en/latest/distributing/#package-data) is that 'my_data_files' should appear in sys.prefix, which would be here for me: '/Users/.../Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User', the files aren't there.

Here is the relevant piece of my setup.py:

```
from setuptools import setup
setup(
    ...
    data_files=[('my_data_files', glob.glob('data_files/*/*.*'))],
    ...
)
```

I don't have a MANIFEST.in file, but my impression was that it shouldn't be necessary.  Any help is much appreciated!

Update:

It looks like this is only an issue when trying to install locally.  If I upload my project to the test PyPI site, then install from there, the data files are installed in the proper location.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Packaging supporting R code in a python module?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5556397/packaging-supporting-r-code-in-a-python-module)